# Como excluir números repetidos dentro de um array em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, array

Sou iniciante em JavaScript e queria sanar a dúvida sobre como excluir números repetidos dentro de um array. A solução que pretendo criar é fazer com que:

- Usuário digita 10 números (sem repetir)
- Ordenar esses números de forma crescente

```js
numeros = []

function adicionar() {
  if (numeros.length >= 10) {
    window.alert('Não é possível inserir mais números.')
  } else {
    num = Number(document.getElementById('cNum').value)
    numeros.push(num)
  }
}

function ordenar() {
  if (numeros.length < 10) {
    window.alert('Números insuficientes. Digite mais números.')
  } else {
    let enumerados = numeros.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b // necessário função demonstrada dentro de sort()
    }) // números como o 10 seja considerado como '10' e não '1' e '0'
    let resp = document.getElementById('resposta')
    resp.innerHTML = `${enumerados}`
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="cNum">Digite alguns números, pois o programa irá ordená-los </label>
  <input type="number" name="tNum" id="cNum">
  <input type="button" value="adicionar" name="tAdc" id="cAdc" onclick="adicionar()">
</p>

<p>
  <input type="button" value="finalizar" name="tBot" id="cBot" onclick="ordenar()">
</p>

<output id="resposta"></output>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de remover você deve pensar na eficiência e não adicionar os números repetidos:

```js
numeros = []

function adicionar() {
  if (numeros.length >= 10) {
    window.alert('Não é possível inserir mais números.')
  } else {
    num = Number(document.getElementById('cNum').value)
    if (numeros.includes(num)) {
      window.alert('Número repetido já adicionado.');
    } else {
      numeros.push(num);
      document.getElementById('adicionados').innerHTML = `${numeros}`
    }
  }
}

function ordenar() {
  if (numeros.length < 10) {
    window.alert('Números insuficientes. Digite mais números.')
  } else {
    let enumerados = numeros.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b // necessário fazer a função dentro de sort()
    }) // números como o 10 sejam considerados como '10' e não '1' e '0'
    let resp = document.getElementById('resposta')
    resp.innerHTML = `${enumerados}`
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="cNum">Digite alguns números, pois o programa irá ordená-los </label>
  <input type="number" name="tNum" id="cNum">
  <input type="button" value="Adicionar" name="tAdc" id="cAdc" onclick="adicionar()">
</p>

<input type="button" value="Finalizar" name="tBot" id="cBot" onclick="ordenar()"></p>

Números adicionados:
<output id="adicionados"></output>
<br/><br/>
Números ordenados:
<output id="resposta"></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para isso, basta verificar se o número já existe no array `numeros` da seguinte forma:

```js
function adicionar () {
  if (numeros.length >= 10 ) {
    window.alert('Não é possível inserir mais números.')
  } else {
    num = Number(document.getElementById('cNum').value)
    // Verifica se num não está em numeros
    if(!numeros.includes(num)) {
      numeros.push(num)
    }                        
  }
}
```

Também é possível colocar `alert` para caso o número já tenha sido inserido para tornar a aplicação mais robusta:

```js
  if(!numeros.includes(num)) {
    numeros.push(num)
  }
  else {
    alert('Número já inserido')
  }
```